# Why do I not see all folders described in the Meteor Application Structure guide?

Tags: meteor

I have been working through the [Meteor Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) and have created my first project in my workspace. 
I do have the list of files as described on the first "Creating an app" page; however, if I reference the [Application structure | Meteor Guide](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure), they are showing more than just the two client and server folders.

Are the folders described in the Application Structure guide, a layout scheme that I need to create, or should the `meteor create simple-todos` command have build this out for the reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have more than client and server folders in a Meteor application. The simple-todos application just uses these two folders, but for more complicated apps your needs can call for a more complex structure.

Before Meteor 1.3 the file loading of Meteor was different. Then you had several other folders that had special functionality, like lib, private, public. From 1.3 this has changed, and now we only have three folders: imports, client and server.

Anything placed inside the imports folder is not loaded by Meteor. Here you put your application code, and then you import it from anywhere outside this folder. This ensures that Meteor only bundles the code that you intentionally state that you will be using. This way you can write code that is not bundled in the app before it is tested and ready for use.

This is explained in the guide:

> To fully use the module system and ensure that our code only runs when
>   we ask it to, we recommend that all of your application code should be
>   placed inside the imports/ directory. This means that the Meteor build
>   system will only bundle and include that file if it is referenced from
>   another file using an import.